# wp_nav_menu() loses 'current-menu-*' classes on single product page within category

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I have my menu set up like so:

- **Shop Online** (WPeC 'Products Page' page)

  - **Product Category** (WPeC Category)
  - **Product Category** (WPeC Category)

    - **Product Sub Category** (WPeC Category)
    - **Product Sub Category** (WPeC Category)
  - ...

Single product pages are viewable from any category or sub category page as they both show the product listing view.

Now when I select either *Shop Online*, a product category or sub-category the menu updates it's CSS classes to match the current hierachy with the usual (example) `current-menu-page`, `current-menu-ancestor` and `current-menu-parent` among others. It doesn't matter if I click on the menu or the category listing on the *Shop Online* page to get there.

For some reason as soon as I view a product singularly (`domain.tld/product-cat/sub-cat/product-single` or `domain.tld/product-cat/product-single`), the menu classes are removed and I lose my menu highlighting because the classes are no longer there.

Is there a way that I can reflect the single product view in the menu by highlighting the current category/ies that the product is in, as well as the `Shop Online` menu item/link respective of how you got to the product?

WP v3.5

WPeC v3.8.9.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for a solution for the same problem, I came across this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_parent_url_menu_class', 10, 2 );

function add_parent_url_menu_class( $classes = array(), $item = false ) {
    // Get current URL
    $current_url = current_url();

    // Get homepage URL
    $homepage_url = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );

    // Exclude 404 and homepage
    if( is_404() or $item->url == $homepage_url ) return $classes;

    if ( strstr( $current_url, $item->url) ) {
        // Add the 'parent_url' class
        $classes[] = 'parent_url';
    }

    return $classes;
}

function current_url() {
    // Protocol
    $url = ( 'on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    // Port
    $url .= ( '80' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return trailingslashit( $url );
}
```

Code from: http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just a quick follow up, it adds the class "parent_url" to the parent list item.

Comment: I'll have to try it out tomorrow, although I've moved on from WPeC to Woocommerce :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Woocommerce plugin you can add class like this

```
    if (
        ($post->post_type == 'product') &&
        ($item->object_id == get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id'))
    ) {
        array_push($classes, 'current-page-ancestor');
    }
```

How To Get WooCommerce Page IDs

```
get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' );
get_option( 'woocommerce_pay_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_edit_address_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_view_order_page_id' ); 
get_option( 'woocommerce_terms_page_id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a bit of a hack, but I ended up using this CSS solution. Took about 5 minutes instead of spending hours trying to figure out how to add `.current-menu-ancestor` into the menu walker with PHP.

Please note that this is a good solution for a custom theme or plugin that is only for one site. Obviously using a specific menu ID doesn't create a general solution that could be used in a theme for the Wordpress.org marketplace, etc.

Original CSS:

```
.current-menu-item > a,
.current-menu-ancestor > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

New CSS:

```
.current-menu-item > a,
.current-menu-ancestor > a,
.woocommerce-page #menu-item-1234 > a /* add your own Store menu item ID here */
{
    color: #000;
}
```

The `woocommerce-page` body class covers:

- store home
- store taxonomy archives
- individual product pages
- cart
- checkout
- probably a bunch of other stuff I'm not thinking of right now
- successfully doesn't target other areas of the site

Answer (score -1):

As explained by a support tech over at [getshopped.org](http://getshopped.org):

> [sic] is actually a limitation of the WordPress menu system. I am
>   unaware of a way to change this behavior. Possibly you could find a
>   menu plugin and make your menu area a widget where you could add the
>   menu by widget that provides an enhanced menu system.